# Getting "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" for package install on npm

Tags: node.js, jquery-plugins, npm, npm-publish, npm-install

I have published a **jRCarousel** jQuery plugin to ***npm***. I initially got the error that name can not contain capital letters, so I have changed that in package.json and then published it got published but on npm website when I try the "Try it out" option I get the "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error. Not sure why is the error as I have specified the dependency in package.json.

Also if there are any changes to only package.json and not to any other files in package or module , how can I update only the package.json file on npm, or do I have to publish it new version no.(which I want to avoid).

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "jrcarousel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "jRCarousel - jQuery Responsive Carousel,
                  a modern, lightweight responsive carousel plugin",
  "main": "dist/jRCarousel.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/vinayakjadhav/jRCarousel.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jquery-plugin",
    "ecosystem:jquery",
    "jQuery Resposive Carousel",
    "jQuery slider",
    "Responsive Slider",
    "Carousel",
    "Slider",
    "Gallery",
    "lightweight"
  ],
  "author": "Vinayak Rangnathrao Jadhav",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/vinayakjadhav/jRCarousel/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/vinayakjadhav/jRCarousel",
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jrcarousel)

[Github Repository](https://github.com/vinayakjadhav/jRCarousel)

[TRY IT OUT Link](https://tonicdev.com/npm/jrcarousel)

Note: I am new to npm, have searched a lot but very less info available related to jquery-plugin publishing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Related useful link about UMD](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/)

Comment: Adding those two tags only increases the tag fragmentation without actual benefit. [tag:npm] is perfectly ok, for handling questions about the commands of npm.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Actually the question is quite related to those commands, as npm is a broad in this case, adding these tags would narrow it down to exactly where the problem was faced. I wanted the information about these commands too, to use them without modifying the version number, as there was no change in code but just the package.json file.

Comment: Yes, they may describe this question more clearly, but do you want to go through the existing 5.8K [npm] question to see if they are also applicable there? I doubt it and if this is not done then those tags don't help anybody, because they cannot be used for categorizing questions, because a lot of questions aren't tagged with them. Additionally, installing and publishing are the two main operations of npm and I don't thing the tags would be sufficiently different from npm, because you can probably add one of the two to at least 80% of npm questions. So, not very useful.

Comment: I still think the question should be narrowed down so that later visitors could be benefited, as many javascript questions gets narrowed down by  fade tags, isnt it

Comment: Can't you clarify this without using tags? You could edit your title (and post body) to include the "real" problem. This would probably be much more useful for finding your question and the answer than using tags. Anyway, if you still disagree, then one of us should probably ask a question about this on meta.

Comment: As suggested, can you please go ahead & ask the question on meta.. If anything is needed from side I can provide that.. Its pretty late (night) here..

Comment: I've reverted my edit and I'm not going to post a meta-question for now. git is a popular example where the number of "subtags" is big and the [community has chosen to keep them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags). This case is a little different, but a lot of the arguments apply. I would still suggest that you improve the title to improve searchability of the question and additionally see if you can add the tag to some popular [tag:npm] questions to "bootstrap" the tag.

Comment: ok.. sure.. thanks.. interesting post..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your plugin with this code. It's the UMD pattern that allows your plugin to run inside browser and most of module bundlers.

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["jquery"], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
        module.exports = factory(require("jquery"));
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function ($) { 
    ...your plugin code goes here...
}));
```

Comment: Thanks @nikita-graf .. I would try that out.. and would look more on UMD pattern.. so If I add this the do I have to publish it again?(as I have to give new version no.)

Comment: Yes, you need to add this code, commit and push everything to repository, then run `npm version patch` and `npm publish` commands.

Comment: Can you please guide me with some more information. As I understand from above code, If client has AMD in project jquery-plugin would be defined as module, If Node then export it and otherwise just a IIFE. So currently (without above code) I am doing the third case right, so does that mean anyone can still use the plugin, and why [Try](https://tonicdev.com/npm/jrcarousel) is giving error.

Comment: Also Is there any other way to push this change without changing the version number as technically I am not changing/fixing the jquery-plugin's core functionality.

Comment: You're absolutely right, currently your code doing the third case, the rest of 2 cases are to support RequireJS and Browserify/Webpack. Tonicdev.com expects your library to be written for nodejs environment, so you need to use CommonJS module definition - `module.exports = ...`

Comment: No, there is no way to update same version of npm package since this fix https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/issues/148

Comment: Thank you so much @nikita-graf for all the information. I am going to accept the answer but as of now I dont want to update the version no. and as you said I already doing the third case(Browser globals), so not going to publish yet. But this was very helpful, learning about UMD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93413/discussion-between-vinayakj-and-nikita-graf).