# Converting a jQuery plugin to an es6 module

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, export, ecmascript-6

Evening all,

Is there a simple way to convert an existing jquery plugin to use the es6 import/export syntax.

for example:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import cycle from 'plugins/jquery-cycle';
```

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't, you'd have to export the plugin, and still attach it to the jQuery prototype etc.

Comment: Is there a common approach for doing this? With the example above I would still expect to use the 'cycle' plugin attached to the jquery prototype... i.e. $.cycle(); Thanks

Comment: Just found this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353406/getting-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-for-package-install-on-npm

Answer (score 1):

I tried solutions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136874/extend-es6-plugin-to-jquery-prototype) with a jQuery plugin([autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)), and it works. Although I have to manually change the originally UMD js file to a ES6-ish module. If the third part libraries are complicated or there are too many of them, I don't think this approach is gonna work well.

That being said, you can give other tools a shot depends on the structure of your project. For example, use jspm and systemjs as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512650/es6-using-babel-traceur-with-jquery-plugins) mentioned. Or use [amd-to-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-to-es6) to convert file format(although this plugin doesn't seem to work well with UMD js file for now). If you are using rollup to bundle ES6 files, you can add this rollup [plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) in rollup config(but it still have some [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/38) with UMD files).